# I want to know how to just use the date portion of the Unix timestamp. I have left blank the portion I am having trouble trying to figure out

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am lost as to how to turn the time stamp into a formal date and how to format it.

```py
import os
import datetime
    
def file_date(filename):
  # Create the file in the current directory
  with open(filename,'w') as file:
    #Create the timestamp
    timestamp = os.path.getmtime(filename)
  # Convert the timestamp into a readable format, then into a string
  date_time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
  # Return just the date portion
  date = ______

  # Hint: how many characters are in “yyyy-mm-dd”? 10
  return ("{}".format(date))
    
print(file_date("newfile.txt")) 
# Should be today's date in the format of yyyy-mm-dd
```

Comment: Since you want to return a string, just use `strftime`, e.g. `return date_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: @MrFuppes thanks so much for the help